# Sharepoint 2013 MySite Increase Quota

Tags: 2013, mysites

we have a SharePoint 2013 Standard edition implementation and 80 users.  We are now starting to use MySites and I want to set up SkyDrive (OneDrive) Pro syncing of their documents from mysites to their laptops but the quota limit is 100MB, which is far too small for users documents.  All users have logged in so their mysites have been set up.  I understand I need to amend each users quota individually but im unsure where to go to do this (central administration?).

If anyone could let me know and also where the MySites Quota template is so I can set it for new users i'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 8):

Go here in Central Admin

- Central Admin > Application Management
- Site Collections > Specify
  quota templates

Under **Edit an existing template** choose **Personal Site**.
Change the values under **Storage Limit Values** to the values you want.

You can see the values for a specific users My Site here

- Central Admin > Application Management
- Site Collections > Configure Quotas and Locks

Under Site Collection choose the individual users My Site

Comment: Is there a way to set a custom  default Quota for MySites so that new ones are adhere to this default.